# Generate random field during load file infile

Tags: mysql

I am trying to generate a random alphanumeric field named Access while importing a .csv file. The .csv file has 3 fields: First_Name, Last_Name, Email. My MYSQL table has 4 fields: First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Access. I need to add a 4th field during import called Access that can just be a random Alphanumeric. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
$handle = @fopen($file,"r"); 

//loop through the csv file and insert into database 

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

$access2 = random_password_length(15);

$temp = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE sendit_emails   
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Email, @Access)
SET First_Name=@First_Name, Last_Name=@Last_Name, 
Email=@Email, '$access2'=@Access";
```

At the bottom of my PHP page I declare the function for random_password:

```
<?php
function random_password_length($length = 15) {
$chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
$password = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, $length);
return $password;
}
?>
```

I am getting a syntax error near @Access. Any help would be appreciated. I am also willing to try another technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need user-variables. Just map the three columns from the CSV to the three relevant DB columns, and use a `SET` statement to set the fourth column.

Something like this should work for you:

```
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE sendit_emails   
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(First_Name, Last_Name, Email)
SET Access='$access2'";
```

Use the following solution for importing a different Access code for each row: Assuming you want to use your existing approach of 15 pseudo-random alphanumeric characters, you can do that in MySQL like this: `SET Access=upper(left(md5(rand()),15))`

Thus the full query would be:

```
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE sendit_emails   
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(First_Name, Last_Name, Email)
SET Access=upper(left(md5(rand()),15))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. While your recommendation imported the Access field, I noticed that all the records have the same Alphanumeric code. Is there a way to get a different random Alphanumeric for every row?

Comment: Sure, just skip the php function and generate the password in MySQL. Assuming you want to use your existing approach of 15 pseudo-random alphanumeric characters, you can do that in MySQL like this: `SET Access=upper(left(md5(rand()),15))`

Comment: That works. Is this method truly random or does it have a pattern? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It should be random enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I edited your response to so it was complete with all of your responses. Many thanks.